# Read Meta Tag Values for Scenario in JBehave

Tags: jbehave

I am not getting the value of tag used with Scenario in JBehave.

```
Scenario: Login
META:
  @dataset LoginTest
Given:
  applicationUrl http://www.gmail.com
When:
  when browser is open
assert:
  exists Login txt_UserName
```

I am using this code:

```
@BeforeScenario()
public void BeforeSc(@Named("dataset") String dataset) {

    System.out.println("@BeforeScenario");  
    System.out.println("Test Name : "+dataset);
}
```

But `dataset` in `BeforeSc` is empty.

I want to fetch the `LoginTest` as `dataset` value in `BeforeSc` method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

@BeforeScenario annotation doesn't support named parameters.
It supports only `ScenarioType` parameter, which can be: ANY, EXAMPLE, NORMAL
See this for details: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/annotations.html

> The @BeforeScenario and @AfterScenario annotations allow the
>   corresponding methods to be executed before and after each scenario.
>   Optionally, the ScenarioType can be specified to execute only upon
>   that type, e.g. for scenarios parametrised by examples.

and also javadoc:
http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/javadoc/core/org/jbehave/core/annotations/BeforeScenario.html

http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/javadoc/core/org/jbehave/core/annotations/ScenarioType.html

BeforeScenario methods are called for **all** scenarios, regardless of they have or not any meta parameters.
If you want to call some method and pass metha parameter to it from some stories, then use "Given" or "When" steps in these stories to do it.